# Proxies: Calling static methods of target's parent when using a proxy object

Tags: javascript, inheritance, static, prototype, es6-proxy

**Really interesting problem here for Javascripters**

In **Javascript**, is possible to intercept when getting a property using **[proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)**.

Also, with a small hack as shown below, is possible to intercept when getting a static property of a class:

```
class Handler{
    constructor(object){
        this.object = object;
    }

    get(target, property){
        if (property === 'all') {
            return () => `selecting data from table: ${this.object.table}` ;
        }
        return target[property];
    }
}
class User{
    static table = 'users'
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(User, new Proxy({}, new Handler(User)));

console.log(User.all()); // prints "selecting data from table: users"
```

**The problem** appears when I am trying to extend the `User` class and then try to call a static method under the `User`'s parent class:

```
class Handler{
    constructor(object){
        this.object = object;
    }

    get(target, property){
        if (property === 'all') {
            return () => `selecting data from table: ${this.object.getTable()}` ;
        }
        return target[property];
    }
}

class Model{
    static getTable(){return this.table;}
}

class User extends Model{
    static table = 'users'
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(User, new Proxy({}, new Handler(User)));

console.log(User.all());
```

Running this will get you `TypeError: this.object.getTable is not a function`.

Debugging the code, I found out that `this.object` is not a `User` class but some sort of a `function`.

**Is it possible, by any workarounds, to call the parent's static method `getTable`?**

**The second problem**, if you manage to fix the first one, is that I cannot instantiate the `User` class anymore:

```
console.log(new User());
TypeError: Super constructor [object Object] of User is not a constructor
```

I think this is for the fact that the `User` is not a class anymore: `console.log(User)` results in `ƒ [object Function]` not `class User extends Model`

**Does the language allow this kind of functionality?**

Answer (score 2):

In your way you can never call `Model`'s `getTable()` because `Model` is not the parent of `User` anymore.

Let's check the prototype chain after this code:

```
class Model{
    static getTable(){return this.table;}
}

class User extends Model{
    static table = 'users'
}

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Model));
// f () { [native code] }
// 'parent' of Model is Function (class is a constructor function in JS)
// Model.[[Prototype]] === Function.prototype

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(User));
// class Model{
//     static getTable(){return this.table;}
// }
// 'parent' of User is Model
// User.[[Prototype]] === Model.prototype
```

Up to this point the prototype chain is like you expect.
But since the statement `Object.setPrototypeOf(User, new Proxy({}, new Handler(User)));` the prototype chain is modified, thus the inheritance looks like this:

```
const userPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(User);
console.log(userPrototype);
// Proxy {}
// 'parent' of User is an instance of Proxy({}, new Handler(User)))

const userPrototypePrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(userPrototype);
console.log(userPrototypePrototype);
// {constructor: ƒ, __defineGetter__: ƒ, __defineSetter__: ƒ, hasOwnProperty: ƒ, __lookupGetter__: ƒ, …}
// 'parent' of Proxy instance is an Object instance (because target of your proxy is {})

Object.getPrototypeOf(userPrototypePrototype);
// null
// 'parent' of Object instance is null (this is the end of prototype chain)
```

As you can see, `Model` is disappeared from the inheritance chain, so you cannot call its `getTable()` method from `User`.

In order to achieve your goals I suggest you a different solution which does not modify the prototype chain directly.

```
class Handler{
    constructor(object){
        this.object = object;
    }
    
    get(target, property){
        if (property === 'all') {
            return () => `selecting data from table: ${this.object.getTable()}` ;
        }
        return target[property];
    }
}

class Model{
    static getTable(){return this.table;}
}

class User extends Model{
    static table = 'users'
}

class ProxyClass {
    constructor(object) {
        return new Proxy(object, new Handler(object));
    }
}

const UserProxy = new ProxyClass(User);
// this is the same as
// const UserProxy = new Proxy(User, new Handler(User))

console.log(UserProxy.all());
// selecting data from table: users

console.log(new UserProxy());
// User {}
```

With this you can dynamically wrap your objects in proxy and you are able to use inherited methods, as well as instantiate model class.

**Important note!**
As mentioned on MDN page [Inheritance with the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain):

> Following the ECMAScript standard, the notation `someObject.[[Prototype]]` is used to designate the prototype of `someObject`. Since ECMAScript 2015, the `[[Prototype]]` is accessed using the accessors [Object.getPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) and [Object.setPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf). This is equivalent to the JavaScript property `__proto__` which is non-standard but de-facto implemented by many browsers.
>
> It should not be confused with the `func.prototype` property of functions, which instead specifies the `[[Prototype]]` to be assigned to all instances of objects created by the given function when used as a constructor. The **`Object.prototype`** property represents the [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) prototype object.